# Error while inserting image into mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql, base64, blob

I am building an Android app in which I am adding the possibility to take photo or select it from the gallery and then send it to the remote php/mysql server.
When I take a photo it is stored successfully and quickly into the server, however when I select it from the Gallery it takes some time before sending an Error

```
 ErrorException: Error while sending STMT_CLOSE packet. PID=99835 in "Path to my php file"
```

I think this error is due to the difference of handling the two cases (take photo or choose an existing one).

This is how my java code looks like:

```
  private Bitmap thumbnail = null;
         ......
             if (options[item].equals("Take Photo"))
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
            else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery"))
            {
                Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

            }


         ......
        // onActivityResult
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            //photo_profile.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        } else if (requestCode == 2) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePath = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePath, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();
            thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }
```

I then create a Byte Array to send to remote server.

```
           byte[] photo = null;
            if (thumbnail != null) {
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
                photo = baos.toByteArray();
            }
```

I then encode the image into string

```
        String image_str = Base64.encodeToString(photo, Base64.DEFAULT);
        params.put("photo", image_str); // add it to the request parameters
```

When I try to print the photo params in my php code I can see that it is too long than the same variable when the photo is captured with the Camera, so I suspect that something is wrong with my encoding.

The photo in my SQL table is of type LONGBLOB and this is the php code part that is launching the error:

```
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE users set name = ?, email = ?, mobile = ?, photo = ? WHERE id = ?");

        $stmt->bind_param("ssssi", $name, $email, $mobile, $photo, $user_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $num_affected_rows = $stmt->affected_rows;
        $stmt->close(); // The above error is triggered here!
```

Does anyone has a clue why this error happens ? am I handling well the case when picture is selected from the Gallery or is there a better and easier way to do it similar to the first case ?

Comment: It's nice to see someone using placeholders. Are you checking for query errors? `mysqli` can be set to emit exceptions which makes errors much harder to miss.

Comment: Yes, just to see if the row was updated or not. I am using Slim framework and the error is not very clear.